# Ringtone Preference not saving choice

Tags: android, preferences, ringtone

I have a ringtone preference in my app but when I select the tone I want, it does not get stored in the preference value. I can click the preference again and it will not show what I just selected.

here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Audio Settings">
        <CheckBoxPreference 
            android:key="SMS_PREF_TTS"
            android:title="Say name of sender"
            android:summary="When a person in your contact list sends you a sms/mms message its says their name"
            android:defaultValue="false">
        </CheckBoxPreference>
        <CheckBoxPreference 
            android:key="SMS_PREF_TTS_MSG"
            android:title="Say Message"
            android:summary="Will say the message of sender from contact list"
            android:dependency="SMS_PREF_TTS"
            android:defaultValue="false">
        </CheckBoxPreference>
        <RingtonePreference 
            android:key="SMS_PREF_SOUND"
            android:title="Change Sound"
            android:ringtoneType="notification"
            android:summary="Select the notification Sound"
            android:dialogTitle="Change Sound"
            android:defaultValue="Silent">
        </RingtonePreference>
</PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

and the weird thing is I just wrote another xml for another part of my app with a ringtone preference looking the same way and that one works so I dont understand.

here is the working one

```
<RingtonePreference
        android:key="CAL_PREF_TONE"
        android:title="Default ringtone"
        android:summary="Select default notification ringtone"
        android:ringtoneType="notification"
        android:defaultValue="Silent"
        android:dependency="CAL_PREF_ON">
    </RingtonePreference>
```

Comment: The only thing I could think of is that you're using SMS_PREF_SOUND in some other pref and this overwrites your choice. Other than that (unless you're doing something in your PreferenceActivity) there's absolutely no reason it won't be stored.

Comment: I have tried changing the `key` too and it still does not save it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up saving it manually by registering a `onPreferenceClickListener` and getting the result

Answer (score 4):

If you have overriden `onActivityResult()` and forgotten to call `super.onActivityResult()` you can see this problem as well.

See [RingtonePreference not firing OnPreferenceChangeListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011883/ringtonepreference-not-firing-onpreferencechangelistener)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.  In the AndroidManifest.xml file I had my preference activity set with `noHistory="true"`.  Once I removed it everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to resolve this by removing `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` and `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` from the settings activity entry on AndroidManifest.xml (setting either or both of these options will cause the same issue). It seems to be a bug on Android.

Answer (score 1):

the solution I used was provided by Udo Held, I just wanted to add one thing, I had to remove the `launchMode="singleInstance"` and I am now using  `android:launchMode="singleTask"` and everything works fine. Just in case someone else needs a launchMode, this one worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, but then I reviewed my codes, when I read the preference:

```
SharedPreferences settings = 
context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Which is wrong, the correct solution is:

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

Hope it helps