# RingtonePreference not firing OnPreferenceChangeListener

Tags: android, android-widget

Every other preference I have fires its OnPreferenceChangeListener.  However, my RingtonePreference it doesn't:

```
p = getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("pref_tone");
String rname = preferences.getString("pref_tone",Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI.toString());
String name = ringtoneToName(rname);
p.setSummary(name);
p.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
    // Never hits here!
    String v = (String) newValue;
    preference.setSummary(ringtoneToName(v));           
    return true;
}
});
```

Comment: This has something to do with the Preference Activity having an onActivityResult method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

onActivityResult had to call super.onActivityResult is the fix

Answer (score 2):

Note that a RingtonePreference uses an Activity for the ringtone picker.

If you are using a RingtonePreference in a support PreferenceFragment (`android.support.v4.preference.PreferenceFragment`) then the RingtonePreference ends up erroneously using the parent Activity instead of the PreferenceFragment when calling `startActivityForResult`. This means that the `onActivityResult` callback gets called on the parent Activity as well. The easiest workaround to fix this problem is to override `onActivityResult` in the parent Activity and make sure it forwards the callback to the PreferenceFragment. For example like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(PREFERENCE_FRAGMENT_TAG);
    if (f != null) {
        f.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those who are still facing problem, if you are using preference fragment then add the following code inside the preference fragment`

```
findPreference(getString(R.string.notification_key)).setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);

@Override
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newVal) {

    if (preference.getKey().equals(getString(R.string.notification_key))) {

        Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getActivity(), Uri.parse(newVal.toString()));
        String name = ringtone.getTitle(getActivity());
        preference.setSummary(name);
    }

    return false;
}

 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    }
```

After this your onPreferenceChange method should get called