# RingtonePreference doesn't save its value

Tags: android, preference

I already worked with some preferences, such as `EditTextPreference`, etc, and all they work, but now I need to use `RingtonePreference`, and it does not work properly. Here's very simple code:

```
  <RingtonePreference
     android:key="my_ringtone_key"
     android:title="Select ringtone"
     />
```

When I click on this preference, id **does** open dialog to select ringtone, but it **does not save it**. I mean, I select ringtone, press "ok", then click this preference again, and still no ringtone selected.

If I try to get value from code, like that:

```
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String tmp = prefs.getString("my_ringtone_key", "none");
```

Then `tmp` have default value "none", which means that value completely isn't stored in `SharedPreferences`.

**BUT**: if I change `RingtonePreference` to `EditTextPreference`, i.e. the following:

```
  <EditTextPreference
     android:key="my_ringtone_key"
     android:title="Select ringtone"
     />
```

Then all works: I can edit the value, value is stored, and of course I can get it from code.

I use API level 7.
I tested this on emulator and two devices, SE Xperia Neo and some Acer.

So, how get `RingtonePreference` to work?
And please add comment if `RingtonePreference` does work for you or not.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing `noHistory="true"`, `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`, and/or `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` from the affected `<activity>` entry in your manifest.

The `launchMode` entry solved the problem for me; I found these solutions recently posted as answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7587668/1992342).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My mistake was overriding the PreferenceFragment's onActivityResult method without calling **super.onActivityResult**, which is where the selected ringtone gets saved.

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10020414/213817